# How to combine two SELECT statements

Tags: sql

I have two queries I am trying to combine into one. A simplified version of what I am doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = '1' ORDER BY `name`
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = '2' ORDER BY `age`
```

I have looked into unions but the examples I find online are less than helpful.

Comment: I think you are looking for  `union` or `union all`. Also which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `where id in (1,2)`.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(1, 2) ORDER BY name, age

Comment: The 'in' throws the error 'unexpected in'.

Comment: Seems odd. Can you add your IN-query to the question?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Which Database you are using ? as 'IN' should totally work

Comment: Yeah the 'in' does work. That was a fail on my part. But it doesn't seem to be working correctly still. It seems to be sorting by name, then by age. I was looking for sorting id = 1 by name, then id = 2 by age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE id in('1','2') 
ORDER BY id,CASE WHEN id=1 THEN age END,CASE WHEN id=2 THEN name END
```

As the id is part of the resultset, there is no need for `UNION` or other complicated tricks.

I'm quite sure, that `age` and `name` are not the same type. One single `CASE WHEN` might get into troubles here.

In my suggestion the `ORDER BY` uses three *columns*. This will translate to

```
ORDER BY 1,age,NULL
```

or to

```
ORDER BY 2,NULL,name
```

Comment: While this does work and I can kinda see why, I am curious how you would modify the order. So for example, if I wanted age to be ASC and name to be DESC.

Comment: That was what I assumed, but I got back an 'invalid syntax' error.

Comment: To be clear though, you mean: ORDER BY id,CASE WHEN id=1 THEN age ASC END,CASE WHEN id=2 THEN name DESC END

Comment: @Robbie No, it is `ORDER BY id,CASE WHEN id=1 THEN age END ASC,CASE WHEN id=2 THEN name END DESC`. Think of the `CASE WHEN ... END` as one single value...

Answer (score 0):

The below code will simply put together the results of each. There isn't much more to it.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = '1' ORDER BY `name`
union
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `id` = '2' ORDER BY `age`
```

Comment: Those ORDER BY's are invalid, and make no sense.

Comment: This wouldn't run?

Comment: Not in ANSI SQL. Perhaps some less strict dbms product will execute it?

Comment: It didn't run for me either using mysql.

Comment: Besides the fact, that this is invalid syntax (the `ORDER BY` must be applied to the outer-most select) there is absolutely no use for `union` at all... This is procedural thinking. The server will not work things down in the order you'd expect this. You might use a table with an `IDENTITY` column and insert both statements one after the other. In this case your table would *combine* both resultsets in the way you seem to expect it here...

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `Union` operator between both queries. Please take care about selecting same column name and sequence into both the queries like below:

```
SELECT id,columnname1,columnname2 FROM table WHERE id = '1'
union
SELECT id,columnname1,columnname2 FROM table WHERE id = '2'
```

Comment: This exactly the same as `select ... from table where id in(1,2)` just with a lot of overhead...

Answer (score 0):

select * from (select   id from table1  where id=1 order by id)              UNION                                                                         select * From (select   id  from table2 where id=2 order by name );  this is working fine with oracle.

Comment: 1) There is no need for `UNION` at all (see existing answers) and 2) Only the *outer-most* `ORDER BY` is relevant. This call might return in differing order from call to call...